# Cant get Child views access in " onGroupCollapse" of Expandable List view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to access the child views of particular group when collapsing it, to get the data of.

Here is the code snippet,

```
expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
@Override
public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
    switch (groupPosition){
        case 0 :
            RadioGroup rg= (RadioGroup) expListView.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.env_group);
```

But i always get `null pointer exception`, can any one explain how can we retrieve child views of particular group in Expandable list view.